# Umbraco on Azure: can I change hostname?

Tags: content-management-system, azure, umbraco, accelerator

I've deployed in Windows Azure a website made with Umbraco, using 
[Windows Azure Accelerator for Umbraco](http://waacceleratorumbraco.codeplex.com/).

For development and test i used a test Hostname. Now it's time to switch to the official DNS hostname..
**How can I change current hostname**?

Actually i configured hostname at deployment time (the only way i know to do this) but i can't deploy again, since many files have been changed working on website on Azure.

---

EDIT

[image]

Let me explain: at the step prompt in the image (during web site deploying) I used as Domain Name "test.mywebsite.com", and configured real DNS.
Now the website is configured, so I'd like to make mywebsite.com point to that site;
But is'nt enough if i configure mywebsite DNS! Shall I deploy again? An will I lose any of the changes I made?

Comment: Did you tried posted in [Umbraco Forum](http://our.umbraco.org/)?

Comment: @balexander yes i posted on umbraco accelerator forum http://waacceleratorumbraco.codeplex.com/discussions/284562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i think that the answers to my questions are:
-Shall I deploy again?  **Yes, i must deploy again**
-Will I lose any of the changes I made? **Many changes will be mantained since are stored into DB. But I have to do many activities to make new website work!**

[This answer](http://waacceleratorumbraco.codeplex.com/discussions/284562) confirms my theory:

> In my case, I created and uploaded a site with a name, let's say
>   http://www.contoso.com and then paid a domain from a registrar let's say
>   http://www.example.com, when I mapped
>   http://MyAcceleratorsService.cloudapp.net/ to my new domain
>   ( http://www.example.com ) and tried to open that domain I got the home page of
>   the Accelerator and not the uploaded site.
>
> I had to upload the site again to Azure (using `UploadUmbracoSite.cmd`
>   from Accelerator application) and when uploading enter the same domain
>   name as the one I registered: http://www.example.com. Then, I was able to
>   browse my uploaded site as expected.
>
> As for your question,  will upload site again using
>   `UploadUmbracoSite.cmd` (is in the Setup folder) and will enter the new
>   domain name when requested.

Exactly what I was trying to avoid.. but the only solution, i suppose.

Well it was not easy to publish again, i got errors of many type (i suppose tied to some components that i've installed after deploy and that are not installed in new deployed website).. i'm going to solve them.

---

### Edit

Completed my work:
- loads of different attempts, no-one worked
- CTP backup of DB
- deleted DB and website
- new full deploy of umbraco
- CTP restore of DB

**finally**:
-all work on content is OK
-all work on styles, pages, templates is lost

### Changing hostname is hard; dont'use test hostname but definitive hostname from the beginning.

### If anyone has suggest, i'll be pleased to test it, anyway

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to make two comments on your question:

1) In order to host your Azure application under a custom host name, you will need to sign up with a DNS provider that supports C-NAME records (most do).  I suggest someone like GoDaddy.com because by default C-NAME records can only resolve your "www.domainname.com" records and cannot do anything for queries where "www." is dropped from the URL.  DNS providers like GoDaddy also have an option to redirect all traffic destined for "domainname.com" to a URL of your choice.  This is a huge deal for Azure apps.  Frankly speaking, it is somewhat disappointing that for all the PaaS and IaaS features of Azure, DNS was not included in the overall package.

2) I am a little worried when you say that you can no longer redeploy your app due to the changes made.  Can you elaborate on that?  Have you made changes to the application's code running on VM's in Azure without going through redeployment process?  If so, this is a huge no-no.  Your VM's running in Azure are not "permanent".  Microsoft and your redeployment process can (and will) re-stage those VM's to the original package at any given time.  Microsoft will re-image your VM's at least once a month during their monthly OS upgrades.  But they can also do so when they need to move your VM to another rack, etc.  Whatever changes that you make to your app must be either stored in source-control before deployment or in a permanent storage facility like SQL Azure, Azure Storage, etc.

HTH

Comment: 1)ok 2)deploy work is a long job, steps in SQL Azure, steps in storage, steps in hosted services. Since I just want to link a different C-NAME I'd like not repeat again deploy sequence

Comment: The issue around "naked" domains isn't entirely with azure: You can't create a CNAME entry for "example.com" as it would effectively have to be created on the TLD record - so you need to create an A record, which has to be an IP address. The way to resolve this in Azure is to use the [Reserved IP feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/) to register an IP address to your service.

Answer (score -1):

This is not really an answer to your question, but it might be a solution to your problem: Use a CNAME record to make the production DNS name point to your development name. E.g. www.productionname.com will the point to www.testname.com. I am not sure if everything will just work out of the box, but it seems to be worth a try.

This requires, that your hosting provider allows you to set up CNAME records.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

Comment: it's not enough: i need to use CNAME but alo to configure Umbraco o Azure to give reponse to that CNAME. but how?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you with that. =(